# How to read JSON key using python in bash

Tags: python, json, bash, shell, sh

In jenkins pipeline, i need to parse json and since I have old jenkins i cannot use plugin to do that.I am trying to parse using python as :

metadataJson has json data

```
sh 'echo metadataJson | python -c "import sys,os, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[os.environ['REPOSITORY']])" '

Error :  unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

I understand that I may need to escape quotes but I am not hitting correct statement.
Can some one tell me the correct statement ?And how can i load the output of this in a variable?

Comment: you can use a CLI tool called `jq`

Comment: as-written, you start and end the `'` within each other, so they must be escaped! .. is it necessary to run this through `sh`?

Comment: yeah ,in jenkins i can run with sh,cannopt use jq because of some permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know I didn't use python, but I believe `jq` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a better tool for your job:

```
KEY=hi && echo '{"hi": 1}' | jq ".[\"${KEY}\"]"                                                                                                                                      
# output: 1
```

to answer your original question, try this (adding `.read()` to your `sys.stdin`):

```sh
echo '{"hi": 1}' | python3 -c "import sys, json, os; print(json.loads(sys.stdin.read())[os.environ['KEY']])"
```

Comment: but if i add sh in front and start from single quotes, then the single quotes needs to be escaped properly. otherwise it takes the single quote around key as termination i think, can you construct a command by adding single quotes before echo and at end?basically a string version of the command